# How to use RegularExpression DataAnnotation with Resource file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources, data-annotations

I am currently using MVC 1.0 and .NET 3.5.  I am using DataAnnotations to validate my model.  I'm trying to add use the RegularExpression to validate a Postcode.  I have stored my Regex in the resource file as many models will use it,  when I try the following:

```
[RegularExpression(Resources.RegexPostcode, ErrorMessage="Postcode format invalid")]
public string Postcode { get; set; }
```

I get the following error when I build:

> An attribute argument must be a
>   constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an
>   attribute parameter type.

Is there any way to use values from a Resource file as the regex or will I need to enter the actual regex string into every model that has a postcode?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest making your own ValidationAttribute.  This will keep the regex in one place as well as the error message.

```
class PostcodeAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public PostcodeAttribute() : base("your regex")
    {
        this.ErrorMessage = "Postcode format invalid";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't leave a comment on the accepted answer as I don't have enough rep.

This accepted answer worked for me, but needed a tweak to work with the unobtrusive javascript validation.  Needed the `IClientValidatable` bits from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18041534/1714585